# Performance benefits of using @cython.final in cdef class?

Tags: cython

I'm currently reading about the `@cython.final` decorator, and I'm wondering whether it adds any **performance benefits** at runtime or only prevents certain actions throwing errors as documented in
https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/extension_types.html

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm wondering whether it adds any performance benefits at runtime

Yes.

The main advantage is when calling `cdef/cpdef` functions. Consider:

```
cdef class C:
    cdef f(self):
        ...

def some_func(C c):
    c.f()
```

without `final` this would call either `C.f` or an overridden function in any derived class. This call looks like:

```
((struct __pyx_vtabstruct_3fnl_C *)__pyx_v_c->__pyx_vtab)->f(__pyx_v_c);
```

(i.e. it goes through a "vtable" and two pointer-dereferences to work out the actual function called.)

With `final` the call looks like

```
__pyx_f_3fnl_1C_f(__pyx_v_c)
```

(i.e. it knows the exact function at compile-time and goes through no pointer-dereferences).

With `cpdef` the difference is even more dramatic because `cpdef` functions may be overridden by derived classes implemented in Python, so the check involves a `dict` lookup too.

There's also some other optimizations:

- Allocation/deallocation of final classes. Again, steps can be skipped because the exact class being allocated is known at compile time.
- Attribute lookup - we know at compile-time if the class has a `__dict__` for each instance.

The optimization of method calls is the main one (and is fairly general and will apply to most languages with have the concept of a "final" type).

Comment: Thanks you very much for your detailled answer!